# Unity WebView for Android VR application

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, webview, virtual-reality

I am making a VR application for Android. I need to use a webview inside the application.

I searched for a webview for unity and I found many webviews, but it has problems when trying to use it with VR application, either they are not working at all or they open as a full screen and they hide all application components.

What I need is a webview that can be used in VR application for Android devices just like this webview: " http://jerome.gangneux.net/images/vr/part4-webview-1280.png ".

I don't care if it is free or I am going to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using webview, I suggest you to use Layout to add UnityPlayer  to that layout. I have tired to do in the following ways,

Step 1 : Generate Android project in build setting from Unity

Step 2 : Copy Data folder from src/asset/Data from generated Android project.

Step 3: Replace Native Android App Data folder (i.e. app/src/asset/Data )

Step 4: Copy UnityPlayerActivity from generated Android project (you can find 3 Unity activities).

Step 5: Keep those 3 activities in Native App. You can use UnityPlayer where you want to add in the layout.

So No need to create Android plugin and add it in Unity project.
Kindly let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Sorry but I didn't understand these steps. Can you make a demo video or a screenshots for these steps?